# Issues catching the 'Page Down'/'Page Up' key events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to catch when the PageUp/PageDown keys are pressed and an element is scrolled, but I've so far been unable to do so. I've tried

Listening for 'keydown' event**: an event triggers when a non-scrolling element is in focus, but when a scrolling element is in focus, no event fires

```
 $(window).on('keydown', function(e)
 {
    console.log(e.keyCode === 34);
 });
```

Listening for 'keypress' event**: no event triggers in any context

```
$(window).on('keypress', function(e)
{
    console.log("keypress"); //does nothing
});
```

Listening for 'scroll' event**: no event triggers in any context

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    console.log("scrolling"); //does nothing
});
```

I'm at a loss and I haven't been able to find any clues.
I've tried my current code in a jsFiddle, and it works fine, so it must be something more specific.

Comment: Forgot to include the brackets in the question, but they're there in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the element I'm trying to scroll on is a SlickGrid table, and it has its own scrolling event.

So I wrote, based on their docs:

```
this.grid.onScroll.subscribe(function(e, args)
{
    console.log(e);
}
```

Now it is triggering on Page Down / Page Up key-presses.

Answer (score 3):

instead of window try to use document so it will consider current document on web page.

in your code there is bracket miss match.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode === 34){
         console.log('page down')
        }

    });
 

    $(document).keypress(function(e){
       console.log("keypress"); //console will print
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with window or document, even if they are attached with `window`these events will fire.

Comment: @chsdk as per my opinion i have given answer i think in programming language there is many more  scenario and many more way of implementation.

Comment: I forgot to include the parentheses in the question, but they are there in my code. Updated my question.

Comment: @DanTheGameMam
check given answer and click on run code snippet.
hope it will help.

Comment: @webdeveloper Your code is fine, but it turns out the issue is that my SlickGrid element is firing its own scrolling event.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try also ?

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
  console.log(event.which === 33) });
```

The event.which property returns which keyboard key or mouse button was pressed for the event

Comment: No improvement. I've tried my current code in a jsFiddle, and it works fine, so it must be something specific to this application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your syntax is incorrect you are missing a closing `)` at the end of your function, you should write:

```js
$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode === 34);
});

$(window).on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log("keypress"); //does nothing
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log("scrolling"); //does nothing
});
```

```css
#scroll {
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">

  <br>fghfjkjgfj
  <br/>dfdfdfdf
  <br/>dfdsf
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>dfdfdf
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>ssdsds
  <br/>fdf
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>fgfgfg
  <br/>End
</div>
```

And everything, will work as expected.

Comment: I forgot to include the parentheses in the question, but they are there in my code. Updated my question.

Comment: @DanTheGameMan On which browser are you running your code?